# liferay portal with asp.net

Tags: java, asp.net, liferay

This is a java noob related question. Have been looking at Liferay portal technology, however I'm a dotnet (c# or vb) developer by day. Does anyone know if you can use the install of liferay to host dotnet code, not just by using the iFrame method of redirecting to a different site - that just sucks in my opinion

Alternatively is the saner option to go down the port my skills back to java?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Definitely port your skills to java, this is biased but I think you will discover a free and rich world of libraries code and community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay is Java Portal framework that runs in a Java Application Server, like Tomcat. Liferay itself and the backing application server can't run .Net code. You will need to use Java and specifically the [Java Portlet Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portlet) in order to do Liferay development.

Comment: to be picky: You actually don't need java. There are examples for portlets in Ruby and PHP. But all in all you're correct: I'm not aware of any .net bridge for Liferay, so I'd still say your answer is correct with regards to the intent of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been worked a Integration Project of Liferay-Java Appliction with c# application. But as of now it was hosted in different websever [I mean c# app was in ISS) . So you can still have a dot net application (with Database (MySql)) and call it from Java Application which is in a Liferay Portal.